# How can I run and end the script() linux command from Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, command-line, scripting

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$sim = "multiq";
`make SCHED=$sim`;
`script > scripter`;
`echo hi`;
print pack("c", 04);
~
```

This script hangs when script is called. Not sure how to get the perl script to keep running.

Comment: What happens if you port this code to a shell script?

Comment: `print pack("c",04)` ? Is that how you are trying to send `^D` to the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that backticks (`‘‘`) run a command and return its output. If you're going to ignore the output, use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) as in

```
system("make SCHED=$sim") == 0 or die "$0: make exited " . ($? >> 8)
```

If you want to fire-and-forget a program (that is, start it in the background without worrying about when it completes), you can use

```
system("script >scripter &");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're have to run that all in one child process if you want it to all interact. See the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for various ways to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect) to control an interactive session

Answer (score 0):

backticks (‘‘) run a command and return its output.So you can store and manipulate it further. If you want to ignore the output, use system(). Also if you want to run any process in background use & in the prefix of the process. For example you wish to start Gimp using your script simply say

```
system("gimp &");
```